# Build swing project using the JavaFX Browser / WebEngine (Gradle)

Tags: java, javafx, gradle, build.gradle, javafx-webengine

I'm trying to build an application using the JavaFX WebEngine inside of a swing gui. Gradle complains about not finding the JavaFX packages. How can I tell gradle to include the appropriate jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using jdk 7.  Add the jfxrt.jar from your jre/lib directory to the build as a file dependency, or install it into your repository.  This is not necessary if you are compiling with jdk 8.

You might also have to put `new JFXPanel()` at the beginning of your Swing app to start the JavaFX thread.

There is also a gradle-javafx plugin that is recommended.  https://bitbucket.org/shemnon/javafx-gradle

Comment: Thank you, adding `jfxrt.jar` as file dependency worked fine. One last question: Do you know if it is independent of the platform or won't the Linux version run using Windows?

Comment: The jfxrt.jar should work on both windows and linux, since it just redirects to the underlying native code.  This is how we deploy our app to windows and linux.  However, you may run into issues running with different JRE versions.  If you intend to distribute, you have to package a JRE with your app or control the version of Java on the user's machine, or package using the JavaFX ant tasks.  Packaging JavaFX in Java 7 is a pain.  Upgrade to Java 8 if you can.